# Firebase BigQuery Export schema

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Is it possible to get gender from firebase exported to bigquery? Gender is in Firebase but it's not in [exported table](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512)
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Age, Gender and Interests are proprietary Google-owned data which are not exported to BigQuery.